# A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found

Tags: python, telebot

Делаю приложение на Tkinter, захотел сделать отправку по телеграмм, все библиотеки подключил, токен указал, указал свой ID и все равно выдает ошибку.

```
token = 'тут токен'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

bot.send_message(мой ВЕРНЫЙ tg id, "hi")
```

и выдает ошибку:

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found
```

Хоть я уже и делал ботов, но тут я не знаю что больше делать.

Comment: Нужен не ID профиля телеграм. Нужен именно ID чата.
Сделай запрос на список чатов или на список полученных сообщений.
У каждого сообщения есть ID чата к которому оно относиться.
При запросе надо писать ID чата, куда отправить сообщение.